# Erro ao tentar mostrar dados do mysql no html

Tags: php, mysql

Estou querendo puxar algumas coisas que está em uma tabela no banco de dados, só que está aparecendo erro na linha da conexao do banco.

bd: Projetos

tabela: projetos

ERRO:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in C:\wamp64\www\admin\index.php on line 8
Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in C:\wamp64\www\admin\index.php on line 8

Codigo

```
<?php
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$host = "localhost";
$db   = "projetos";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$query = sprintf("SELECT nome, descricao, download FROM projetos");
// executa a query
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>
```

Comment: Você escreveu errado aqui: `mysql_pconnect`. Não existe essa função na API. O certo é `mysql_connect`. Só isso.

Comment: Considere usar funções `mysqli_*` pois as funções `mysql_*` forma depreciadas.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar o método `mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass)` tente instanciar um objeto mysql, ou seja `new mysql(localhost, root, senhadobanco, nomedobanco)`

Comment: Agora da outro erro '-'


( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in C:\wamp64\www\admin\index.php on line 6 ( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in C:\wamp64\www\admin\index.php on line 6